# Is it possible to run shared computer vision model on camera in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: android, ios, machine-learning, computer-vision, kotlin-multiplatform

Let's assume I have camera stream from IOS / Android. What kind of stream should it be? Can I have the same implementation for both platforms for running model on this stream? The model concerns object detection.

I have not found any library providing such a feature. Did someone try anything similar?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.